# Find sum of unique values based on another distinct column

Tags: sql, oracle

I am new to Oracle. I work on Oracle Database 12c version.There are two datafile copies for one file#. I need to calculate the total size of backup datafile copies only for second set of file# without including the first copy.

Output of query shows two or more copies for one file#

If I sum up to find total size of the datafile, it displays the sum of both datafile copies.

```
SQL> select sum((datafile_blocks)*8/1024) from v$BACKUP_DATAFILE;

SUM((DATAFILE_BLOCKS)*8/1024)
-----------------------------
                    10738.375
```

I require only the total size of either first copy or second copy

```
SQL> select file#,count(*),sum((datafile_blocks)*8/1024) from v$BACKUP_DATAFILE group by file#;

     FILE#   COUNT(*) SUM((DATAFILE_BLOCKS)*8/1024)
---------- ---------- -----------------------------
         1          2                          1900
         6          2                      3588.625
         2          2                         32.25
         5          2                          2500
         4          2                           670
         8          2                         87.25
         3          2                          1780
         7          2                         32.25
         9          2                       108.125
        10          2                            20
         0          4                        19.875

11 rows selected.
```

If I group by with having clause, it displays 0 rows

```
SQL> select sum((datafile_blocks)*8/1024) from v$BACKUP_DATAFILE group by file# having count(file#)=1;

no rows selected
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you want to *dismiss* some `file#`s?

On my 18cXE, there are "duplicate" `file#` values, but - see `datafile_blocks` - they are different

```
SQL> select file#, datafile_blocks, block_size
  2  from v$backup_datafile
  3  order by file#;

     FILE# DATAFILE_BLOCKS BLOCK_SIZE
---------- --------------- ----------
         0             646      16384
         0             646      16384
         1          121600       8192  --> different DATAFILE_BLOCKS for
         1          106240       8192  --> the same FILE#
         2           25600       8192
         3           61440       8192
         3           65280       8192
         4           26880       8192
         4            8320       8192
         5           51200       8192
         7             640       8192
         7             640       8192
         8            1288       8192

13 rows selected.
```

---

Anyway, to answer your question: how about dividing sum you already calculated with value `count(*)` returns? Something like this (see line #5) (I used your query):

```
SQL> select file#,
  2         sum(datafile_blocks * 8 / 1024) sum_blk,
  3         count(*) cnt,
  4         --
  5         sum(datafile_blocks * 8 / 1024) / count(*) result
  6  from v$backup_datafile
  7  group by file#;

     FILE#    SUM_BLK        CNT     RESULT
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1       1780          2        890
         7         10          2          5
         2        200          1        200
         8    10,0625          1    10,0625
         4        275          2      137,5
         5        400          1        400
         3        990          2        495
         0   10,09375          2   5,046875

8 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: Is there anyway to get the sum of recent copies of those file#? Dividing by count(*) would not give accurate size of files if file grows over time.

Comment: That's why I asked whether you REALLY want to do that. It looks as if - in your database - those rows look exactly the same so you'd want to remove one of them (in my database, they are different). To do that, you'd just divide SUM with COUNT and get an *average*, which is - actually - `avg(datafile_blocks * 8 / 1024)`.

Comment: How to sum up the 'result' column total without displaying individual size?

Comment: Use "this" query as a subquery and select SUM(RESULT) from it.

Answer (score 1):

If i get it right, you need only the last statement for each file. Do you?

In this case I'd suggest smth like this:

```
with 
    t as (
        select file#, 
               datafile_blocks * 8 / 1024 sum_blk,
               checkpoint_time,
               row_number() over (
                         partition by file# 
                         order by checkpoint_time desc) desc_row_no 
          from  v$backup_datafile 
    )
select * 
  from t 
 where desc_row_no = 1
```